# Updating unknown Immutable.js Map structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, immutable.js

My task is to update deep nested values for which I don't know the path because the data is dynamic.

Example:

```
const errors = Immutable.fromJS({
  clients: [
    {
      users: {
        names: ["Joseph", "John"],
        items: ["Passport", "ID"],
      },
    },
  ],
  items: {
    data: {
      codes: ["543", "765", "549"],
    },
  },
});
```

Desired output:

```
const errors = Immutable.fromJS({
  clients: [
    {
      users: {
        names: "Joseph,John",
        items: "Passport,ID",
      },
    },
  ],
  items: {
    data: {
      codes: "543,765,549",
    },
  },
});
```

In this case, I need to concatenate all the strings inside the nested arrays (lists). I can join the nested array, but I need to somehow get to it first. I was thinking about getting the `Map` nested structure, but haven't found a method for it (only for keys at the same level). Can this be done in Immutable.js? If so, how?

Comment: Post your current attempt (code),  and the desired output.

Comment: If you don't know the path, then I guess you will have to search the object for a property with a given name - or because of duplicates, possibly search for a specific subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use recursivity to parse and update the lists containing strings/numbers:

```js
let errors = Immutable.fromJS({
  clients: [
    {
      users: {
        names: ["Joseph", "John"],
        items: ["Passport", "ID"],
      },
    },
  ],
  items: {
    data: {
      codes: ["543", "765", "549"],
    },
  },
});

const update = (object) => {

    if (typeof object.map === 'function') {
        return object.map((value) => {
            if (Immutable.List.isList(value) && 
                value.every((val) => ['string', 'number'].includes(typeof val))
            ) {
                return value.join();
            }
            
            return update(value);
        });
    }
    
    return object;
}

errors = update(errors);

console.log(errors);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```